# Contour cut of a 3d graph in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I cut off a 3D graph in Matlab at a particular contour set (e.g., the graph `x^2+y^2` shall have a clear upper edge like a glass)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Two methods you may use for slicing a 3-D plot.

- (left) setting `NaN` above and below two thresholds (*@Molly's proposal*)
- (right) using the `ZLim` property of the current `axes`, using the exact same thresholds.

You can see that `NaN` respects the tiles created with `surf`, so it works at the `surf` level. On the other hand, `ZLim` creates nicely cut graph, even through the tiles - it works at the rendering level.

Finally, to have a better cut using `NaN`, you can define a finer grid (`meshgrid(-10:0.01:10, -10:0.01:10)` for example) but you will still depend on the mesh created. In addition, the `ZLim` method will only easily work for slicing at constant `z` (but this what a contour is about).

The following plot

[image]

is produced by

```
[x y] = meshgrid(-10:10,-10:10);
z = x.^2+y.^2;
figure

%%%% solution 1 (NaN)
z_trim = z;
z_trim(z_trim<100) = NaN;
z_trim(z_trim>150) = NaN;

subplot(1,2,1);
surf(z_trim)
set(gca, 'Visible', 'off');
view(-20,30)


%%%% solution 2 (ZLim)
subplot(1,2,2);
surf(z)
set(gca,'Zlim',[100 150], 'Visible', 'off');
view(-20,30)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set values above the cutoff to `nan`:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-100:100,-100:100);
Z = X.^2+Y.^2;
ind = Z > 10000;
Z(ind) = nan;
mesh(X,Y,Z)
```

[image: example]